# Excel loop hangs after trying to manipulate data (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have written a simple nested for loop in VBA that loops through records in my worksheet and, if it finds some values on basis of conditions, copies the value in the current worksheet.

The values of `NumRows` and `NumRowSTGSales` are 4000 and 8000 respectively. When I run the code, Excel just hangs

```
Dim curRowNo As Long
curRowNo = 2
NumRowSTGSales = Worksheets("Worksheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
NumRows = Worksheets("Worksheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
' Select cell a1.

' Looping through GL accounts

'Looping through items in GL accounts
For y = 2 To NumRows
    'Looping through customer code found in sales data
    For z = 2 To NumRowSTGSales
        dataGL = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(y, "A").Value
        dataItem = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(y, "B").Value
        itemSales = Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(z, "F").Value
        If dataItem = itemSales Then
            dataCustomer = Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(z, "E").Value
            Worksheets("CurrentWorksheet").Cells(curRowNo, "A").Value = dataGL
            Worksheets("CurrentWorksheet").Cells(curRowNo, "B").Value = dataItem
            Worksheets("CurrentWorksheet").Cells(curRowNo, "C").Value = dataCustomer
            curRowNo = curRowNo + 1
        End If
    Next z
Next y
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are funning the inner part of the internal loop about 32,000,000 times? Moreover, each loop you are making several references? When you say **it hangs**, how long did you wait for it to complete?

Comment: Press control+break and hoover over `y` an `z` to check their values and see if it's stuck or looping. Eventually use F8 to step through your code

Comment: I just ran a simulation with your code, I "only used" 300 rows in `Worksheet1` , and 300 rows in the `Worksheet2` , it took the Macro more than 3 minutes to complete (3 minutes and 17 seconds). So just imagine running you code that had more than a 100 times of data.

Comment: What you need to do is use the `Vlookup` function, it will shorten your run-time, as you will not have to loop through the entire second worksheet.

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you for your quick response, Even if i use the Vlookup, will that be possible? because in Worksheet 2  there might be multiple values that are matching for one item  eg, say 1 value in column a is matching in 2nd worksheet column a ,  i have to pick the corresponding column c from 2nd worksheet. But there might be more than one value that matche in the second worksheet. I have to pick those too.

Comment: Its worth noting that the speed might improve if you set the values of dataGL and dataItem in the first loop, rather than assigning them to the same value ever single time the inner loop runs.  I'm not sure what scale of a difference this will make in terms of time, but it will certainly reduce it even minutely

Comment: One thing you can do is to transfer all of the data into VBA arrays, process the arrays in memory, and after the loop transfer the data back. That will involve something like 4 data transfers to/from the spreadsheet, rather than 100 million.

Comment: @RGA That is a smart thing which i have overlooked, let me improve upon that,

Comment: @John Coleman I guess that is the final step i will need to perform.

Comment: @abhinavm93 Are you aware that entire ranges can be transferred to VBA arrays (or vice-versa) in just 1-line of code? A rather minor modification of your code should improve it by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Also: Try to analyze your data again and take a hard look at it. Sometimes you can save a lot of computing time, if you clean up your data in a way, that there are only those values left, that you really need.

Comment: @JohnColeman No , Can you englighten me , im really not well versed in VBA

Comment: @abhinavm93: It's as easy as that: `Dim Arr() As Variant` 
`Arr = Range("A1:B10")`

Comment: @Tom How do i do this dynamically, say i dont have a defined range , how do i define the array then? Say im populating a sheet , whatever the contents of the sheet are say its A1 to C15 once, the next time its A2 to B20 how do i initialise this?

Comment: Just google for "allocate arrays dynamically vba" :)

Comment: In your response to @RGA you indicated that you couldn't use VLOOKUP because you might have several things (`itemSales`) in worksheet2 which might match something (`dataItem`) in worksheet1. Hence the itemSales aren't unique. What about the dataItems? Does each `dataItem` occur in worksheet1 in just one place?

Comment: @JohnColeman I never said anything about VLOOKUP... :P  think you meant to tag OP in that comment

Comment: @Rga -- sorry. I forgot who brought up VLOOKUP in the brief time it took me to scroll to the bottom of the page to paste a new comment. I must be getting old.

Comment: @JohnColeman No worries!  normally I wouldn't even have noticed myself except for the fact that as well as I know VBA I do not for the life of me have any idea how to properly use VLOOKUP... I actually started teaching myself VBA originally specifically because I couldn't figure out how to make VLOOKUP work so I went out and wrote my own :P

Comment: @JohnColeman In worksheet 1, each item is unique, however in worksheet 2 there might be multiple entries for the same items, to add a bit of understanding, i have to pick the corresponding customer to which that item was sold to, so i am using the double loop. picking each item from worksheet 1, checking it in worksheet 2 and then writing the customer for the same in my current worksheet.

Comment: @abhinavm93 have you tried my code below with VLookup, it's much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code using ***VLookup*** function speeds up the process by a lot.
I tested it, but I don't know exactly what types of data you are keeping in your Excel worksheets - can you upload a screen shot of the titles and 1-2 rows of data per worksheet, just to understand what types of data you have, and also the structure of the records tables.

Anyway, here is the piece of code I got:

```
Sub Compare_Large_Setup()


    Dim curRowNo                            As Long

    curRowNo = 2

    NumRowSTGSales = Worksheets("Worksheet1").UsedRange.Rows.count
    ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
    NumRows = Worksheets("Worksheet2").UsedRange.Rows.count

    Dim VlookupRange                        As Range
    Dim result                              As Variant

    ' set Range of VLookup at Worksheet2
    Set VlookupRange = Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range("F2:F" & NumRows)

    'Looping through items in GL accounts
    For y = 2 To NumRowSTGSales
        On Error Resume Next
        result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(y, "B"), VlookupRange, 1, False)

        ' no match was found with VLlookup >> advance 1 in NEXT loop
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            GoTo ExitFor:
        End If

        ' successful match found with VLookup function >> copy the records to "CurrentWorksheet" sheet
        Worksheets("CurrentWorksheet").Cells(curRowNo, "A").Value = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(y, "A").Value
        Worksheets("CurrentWorksheet").Cells(curRowNo, "B").Value = result
        Worksheets("CurrentWorksheet").Cells(curRowNo, "C").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(y, "B"), VlookupRange, 4, False)
        curRowNo = curRowNo + 1

ExitFor:
    Next y


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a quotation mark in one of the lines. One quick fix, but probably not the solution to the problem is to add a 'DoEvents' in the loops to keep it from freezing.

```
Dim curRowNo As Long
curRowNo = 2
NumRowSTGSales = Worksheets("Worksheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
NumRows = Worksheets("Worksheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
' Select cell a1.

' Looping through GL accounts

'Looping through items in GL accounts
For y = 2 To NumRows
    'Looping through customer code found in sales data
    For Z = 2 To NumRowSTGSales
        dataGL = Worksheets("Worksheet1").cells(y, "A").Value
        dataItem = Worksheets("Worksheet1").cells(y, "B").Value
        itemSales = Worksheets("Worksheet2").cells(Z, "F").Value
        If dataItem = itemSales Then
            dataCustomer = Worksheets("Worksheet2").cells(Z, "E").Value
            Worksheets("CurrentWorksheet").cells(curRowNo, "A").Value = dataGL
            Worksheets("CurrentWorksheet").cells(curRowNo, "B").Value = dataItem
            Worksheets("CurrentWorksheet").cells(curRowNo, "C").Value = dataCustomer
            curRowNo = curRowNo + 1
        End If
    DoEvents
    Next Z
DoEvents
Next y
```

Comment: I used the doEvents property when i was looping, it did keep the excel from freezing but ran in an hour through 32 000 000 records, the answer i posted which im finally using runs in around 3-4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your useful answers, the final approach i used to solve this problem was to add a pivot table for the data i wanted to go through, i then dynamically added a filter in the pivot table for that particular item instead of looping through 1000's of records through code.

I then picked up each corresponding customer through the pivot table.

Sample code for the same is shown below:

```
Dim itemCustSalesWS As Worksheet
        Set itemCustSalesWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales item customer pivot")
        Dim itemCustSalesPivot As PivotTable
        Set itemCustSalesPivot = itemCustSalesWS.PivotTables("Item Customer Pivot sales")
        itemCustSalesPivot.PivotFields("Item_Code").Orientation = xlPageField
        'Filtering here
        Dim pf As PivotField
        Set pf = Worksheets("Sales item customer pivot").PivotTables("Item Customer Pivot sales").PivotFields("Item_Code")
        With pf
        .ClearAllFilters
         .CurrentPage = dataItem
         End With

         With itemCustSalesWS.UsedRange
         itemCustfirstrow = .Row
         itemCustfirstcol = .Column
         itemCustlastrow = .Rows(UBound(.Value)).Row
         itemCustlastcol = .Columns(UBound(.Value, 2)).Column
        End With

        'The following loop runs for the current filtered item FROM SEQUENCE 1 IN SALES ITEM CUSTOMER PIVOT, and maps
        'their amount  in front of the GL accounts and items
        For z = 4 To itemCustlastrow - 1

        'Logic for calculation of Sequence 4 goes here
        dataCustomer = Worksheets("Sales item customer pivot").Cells(z, "A").Value
        sumItemCust = Worksheets("Sales item customer pivot").Cells(z, "B").Value

        Worksheets("Item customer mapping").Cells(curRowNo, "A").Value = dataGL
        Worksheets("Item customer mapping").Cells(curRowNo, "B").Value = dataItem
        Worksheets("Item customer mapping").Cells(curRowNo, "C").Value = dataCustomer
        Worksheets("Item customer mapping").Cells(curRowNo, "D").Value = seq1Amount
        Worksheets("Item customer mapping").Cells(curRowNo, "E").Value = volumePerItem
        Worksheets("Item customer mapping").Cells(curRowNo, "F").Value = sumItemCust
```

Thank you all for the help and quick responses.